# Change background to the last entry in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, colors

I'm doing a simple jQuery code which contains one text form and two buttons. The idea is that I should be able to enter a rgb color or color in the text form, then press "Add color" button to add it to an array, then press "Change color" button to change the background-color to the one I just added.

My question is regarding the function that is bound to the Change color button, how do I bind it to change it to the color I just added?

Now when I use Math.random() it, of course, chooses a random color from the array. I've tried reading on about Math module but can't find something like Math.latest() (bad explanation, but I think I covered what I need help with)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var color = ['green', 'orange', 'yellow'];

    jQuery('#changeBG').click(randomBackground);

    jQuery('#addColor').click(function(){
        color.push($('#addToList').val());
        $('#sampleBoard > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>',$('#addToList').val(),'</td><td><div id="sample" style="border:solid 1px                                         black;width:18px;height:18px;background:'+$('#addToList').val()+'"></div></td></tr>');
    });


    function randomBackground(){
        jQuery('body').css({'background-color': color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]});
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `jQuery('body').css({'background-color': color[color.length - 1]});`

Comment: It was that easy, thanks alot Vikram. Write it as a response (and not comment like you did now) next time so users can upvote the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest array element is the one "to the end" because `push()` adds it there. You can get it by

```
var latestColor = color[color.length - 1];
```

Remember: Indices are zero-based, so an array with length `l` has its last element at index `l - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

var newcolor=color[Math.floor(Math.random() % color.length)]}

Use '%' operator

doing this will give you random color index

I hope this will work